# Oracle Apex 4.1 Checkbox to update shuttle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am fairly new to APEX and need some help please.
I am running Apex 4.1 on 11g database.

I have check box field P6_LOCATION, with list of locations and there is dynamic action assigned to field. Dynamic action on **click** should **refresh** shuttle with list of properties from selected locations ( it can be one or many). So I can see that on click shuttle 'blinks' as if  it refreshed however it does not change number of elements displayed. If I submit page however, shuttle displays different (updated) number of elements. Shuttle code :

```
 SELECT name||' '||NEIGHBOURHOOD,property_id 

FROM property_table

where

instr(':'||:P6_location||':',':'||to_number(location)||':') > 0
```

This code does work however not when I am calling it. From session point of view I can see that P6_LOCATION value is changing...

Any help, guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: I ended up adding button to partially refresh page. As this is not ideal solution if you know how this can be achieved better please I am still interested.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that although the shuttle refreshes it does not "know" the new checkbox value and thus refreshes with the same selection.

Here is a discussion that seems to handle the same issue:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2171164&start=0&tstart=0

Not sure if you find an answer in that thread.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried few approaches and none of them worked unfortunately.